# ASN 1 UPER encoder/decoder

Tags: java, encoding, bouncycastle, decoding, asn.1

I wanted to encode and decode a message in a JAVA project according to UPER standard of ASN 1. Apparently [JAC (Java Asn.1 Compiler)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jac-asn1/) and BouncyCastle doesn't support PER and UPER encoder and decoder. Is there any other tools for JAVA?
I appreciate any help

Comment: I found a tools i.e. MARBEN ASNSDK TCE-Java. It apparently support UPER in ASN 1 for encoding and decoding. but the problem is how to use this tools in a JAVA eclipse project?
I appreciate any help
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[ITU-T maintains a list of applications online](http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx), although I'm not sure that any of the free ones support Java and PER/UPER. Almost all of the commercial products do, however, and you should be able to find free evaluations online for them.

If you're willing to use C instead of Java (and possibly expose the APIs using JNI), [there is an open source compiler by Lev Walkin](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) available. I'm not sure how good the PER support is (he doesn't say he supports canonical PER encoding, for example—just basic). He also qualifies the support for Information Objects (a common feature in many 3GPP specifications) as "basic," which is a bit vague.

All in all, the open-source applications are a bit of a mixed bag by comparison to the commercial applications. This is no real surprise (ASN.1 is complicated!), but it makes it hard to get by on a null budget.